# Find how many people downloaded my App

Tags: ios, itunes

I know about **Google Analytics**  but don't want to use and before I used below iTunes API for get some information

```
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.myappBundelID.com
```

It not provided Downloaded peoples count so.

Anybody have any ideas how to display How many peoples download my App ?

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn’t provide this data. You can try many 3rd party tools to extract this data but all these tools will give you an estimated data which can sometimes be misleading.

I hope this was helpful. :)

Comment: Which  3rd party can provide this data?

Answer (score 0):

They are available in iTunes Connect -> Sales and Trends.